# Re-Use Angular 2 Form Components

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, code-reuse

I am currently working on an *Angular* project and would like to be able to reuse my form components for both the **creating** and **updating** of entities.

For example, I have a **User** entity on a remote API and I have a form on the front end that allows me to create these users and **POST** the input to the server. This works great!

The issue begins when trying to use the same form for updating. I need to fill the form input fields with the stored information from the remote server by making a *GET* request. The issue is that the form component loads before the *REST* request *Observable* responds with the **User** entity.

**How can I fill a form with information from a remote server before the form is fully loaded?**

Comment: If you use the router you can use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) to delay rendering of the form until data is available, but probably a simpler approach would be to build the form in a way it doesn't break if the data is not yet available. Please provide more information about your concrete use case. I also don't see how the problem of rendering before data is available is related to re-using form components.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer because on updates, the form will first display as empty and a few seconds later when the request resolves, the form is filled with information. It very not esthetic to see the form flash information suddenly.

Comment: use `ngModel` to bind the values to the form, by doing so when the entryies are availabel your form get load properly. otherwise use *ngIf on the top of form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ngIf`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'xxx',
  template: `
<form *ngIf="model">
  ...
</form>

<!-- optional -->
<my-spinner *ngIf="!model"></my-spinner>
`})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService:MyService) {
    this.myService.getData.subscribe(data => this.model = data);
  }
}
```

then `*ngIf` adds the form to the DOM as soon as `this.model = data` is executed.

Comment: is this the cleanest approach?

Comment: @gunter what is my-spinner here ?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg (yet to be created ;-) )

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I'd say this depends on your requirement and how you want to entertain the the user while he's waiting especially if it takes seconds. I would show the form immediately in a disabled state and also display some loading indicator inside the form (or a global one if you have one on your page - like the footer - depends again on the kind of your app) until the data is available.